# Where should unstructured files be committed in SVN?

Tags: file, svn, tortoisesvn

I realize that the purpose of SVN is to store structured files for an application or for some other purpose that have standard names, and updates to these files are committed, becoming revisions.

We know that files in SVN are typically environment agnostic.  I'm defining environment as DEV, QA, UAT and PROD.  Suppose we mix QA and UAT "unstructured" files into this, and want to keep track of QA scripts, QA automation scripts, screen shots, proposed documentation for defects that were fixed, business requirements for a piece of development, etc..?  Essentially, we want a place to store these unstructured files.  Where in the structure below would we store such a thing, or is this not recommended?

Since branches are smaller project work (or task work) within a larger project (or application), we store pieces of development within a branch sub-folder.  Trunk is a stable version of what's in production, right?  In the past, I've heard that tags is where deployment and rollback scripts should live, and anything at some point in the past, that is more or less static.  So I'm thinking we either put these unstructured files in branches or tags.

The reason I say "unstructured" is because we may have QA screen shots that may be different for each piece of development and might become obsolete later on.  We obviously don't want to check these back into trunk after development, but during development, a screen shot may change as new development changes get checked into a branch before that branch is actually stable, so we may want to overwrite that screen shot with the newer screen shot.  Also, test scripts will change as development changes.  We also have business requirements for development, test plans for DEV and for QA, test results for DEV and QA, descriptions of defects found before development, and descriptions of fixes for defect development, etc...

Here is the structure we currently have:

```
\app
\app\trunk\
\app\trunk\file_x
\app\branches\
\app\branches\YYYY-MM-DD_branch_x\file_x
\app\tags\
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation's files and tests are good candidates to be a content of separate tree in repo (shared with app-sources or external, linked to app-repo with svn:externals). Repository may be something like

```
/trunk
/tests
/docs
```

in result

Other QA-work (bug-hunting) is a subject of (some, any, preferred) issue-tracking system: found bugs are added  into it (with descriptions, steps-to-reproduce, screenshots), can be discussed in ticket's comments, have related to bug commits (linked from tickets also)

Comment: +1 .. based on your experience, what structure do you tend to use under these 3 folders?

Comment: @MacGyver - I'll prefer flat space under `/tests` and `/docs` (because in my *ideal case* it will be dir-based externals from independent repos's /where main work happens/ mainlines)